# Countable-additivity measure's statement equivalent to a given limit statement for nested sets

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am going through the Russian notes on probability theory (Higher School of Economics) and they define countable additivity as (pardon me for my translation skills):

> Numeric (real-valued?) function $\mu$ on $A$ on $\sigma$-algebra
>   $\mathcal{A}$ is called a measure (countable-additive measure), if:
>   $$\mu(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n), A_i \cap
> > A_j = \emptyset, i \neq j$$

Not exactly sure whether that definition refers to a sequence of nested classes $A_n$ ($A_n \subset A_{n+1}, \cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\emptyset$).

But then the exercise is the following:

> Prove, that countable-additivity property is equivalent to the
>   statement $\lim_n \mu(A_n) = 0$ for a sequence of nested classes
>   $\{A_n\}$ (as I have defined above).

I am not sure where to start with that at all. However, I have arrived at this trivial conclusion (I hope that the steps are correct?), which is just the given in the question... so well done.

1. We know that the sequence is nested (and $\cap A_n = \emptyset$) so:
   $$\lim_n A_n = \emptyset$$
2. Apply a measure:
   $$\mu(\lim_n A_n) = \mu(\emptyset)$$
   $$\lim_n \mu(A_n) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

> Not exactly sure whether that definition refers to a sequence of nested classes

No, it doesn't. All what is required in the definition is that the $A_i$ be paiwise disjoint (please suppress the inequality sign just after your first "cap", it won't harm).

It seems that the finite additivity is contextual.

Now you have to prove equivalence

1) [limiting property $\Longrightarrow$ countable additivity] You have disjoint classes take $B_n=A\setminus (\cup_{j\leq n} A_{j})$ and apply the limiting property

2) [countable additvity $\Longrightarrow$ limiting property] You have nested classes, take $B_n=A_n\setminus  A_{n+1}$ and apply countable additivity.